# How can I get pagination links from ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

(laravel 4).

In my view I have:

```
$posts->links();
```

That displays posts pagination and works fine,
then I decided to have a search field that works with ajax.
the problem is that when I search something I need to change the Pagination too. (the new results pagination).

I tried something like this on my PostsAjax function:

```
$posts=Post::where(...)->paginate(9);
foreach($posts as $post){
$results.='<li>..</li>';
}
$data=array('results'=>$results, 'pagination'=>$posts->links());
            return Response::json($data);
```

but the ajax response data.pagination its empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you return the result of your search in your controller, something like this:

```
return Post::where(...)->paginate(9);
```

the output will be:

```
{
    "total":14,
    "per_page":10,
    "current_page":1,
    "last_page":2,
    "from":1,
    "to":10,
    "data":
        [
            {post_id: 1, title: 'your_search'},
            {post_id: 2, title: 'your_search'}
        ]
}
```

to get the next page, you must do the request to the same url with the query string page `www.example.com/searchpost/key?page=2`.